Is our knowledge of physics (and of everything that reduces to or supervenes on the physical) analytic or synthetic, and is it empirical or a priori?
My question is inspired by the related but much narrower question: Is number π empirical or a priori?.
The aforementioned question includes an excellent introduction, which I will quote to provide a convenient framing for this discussion:

Kant classified statements into 4 epistemic categories based on two
criteria: The Analytic/Synthetic distinction (Are statements true by
definition or do we need outside information to determine their truth)
and the A Priori/A Posteriori distinction (Are they independent of
empirical evidence or not).
In particular he arrived at the existence of synthetic a priori
truths, in opposition to Hume who believed that all statements were
either analytic a priori or synthetic a posteriori.
Neither Kant nor Hume believed that analytic a posteriori truths are
possible.

Given this introduction, I ask: Is our knowledge of physics analytic or synthetic, and is it a priori or a posteriori? The question becomes particularly intriguing when we consider that physics is deeply intertwined with mathematics and logic, disciplines that are widely regarded as analytic and a priori. This is especially true of theoretical physics.
The issue becomes even more puzzling when we look at the matter from the perspective of physicalism, the metaphysical view that everything is physical or supervenes on the physical. If we put on physicalist glasses, it seems that we would need to accept that mathematics and logic either reduce to physics or supervene on it, thus placing physics at a more fundamental level. Consequently, if we claim that our knowledge of physics is synthetic and empirical, it would appear to follow that our knowledge of mathematics and logic must also be synthetic and empirical—contrary to the popular, common-sense view that they are analytic and a priori. (See also: Under physicalism, what is the ontological status of the laws of logic, and what is their relationship to the laws of physics?)
Is our knowledge of physics—and, by extension, of everything that reduces to or supervenes on the physical—analytic or synthetic, and is it empirical or a priori?

Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

The current view in physics is that physics operates empirical and is not a-priori. In addition physical theories are synthetical.
That's different from Kant, who considers some statements from Newton's mechanics to be synthetical a-priori.
According to Popper: Science makes hypotheses, which are to be confirmed or refuted.

You seem to be confusing ontology with epistemology. If nothing exists, there is nothing to “know”. From a physicalist’s perspective, mathematical concepts do not in a literal sense exist. They are merely “representations” of truths about the physical world.
However, a physicalist can still use the terms apriori knowledge vs empirical knowledge. Apriori knowledge would refer to parts of the physical world that couldn’t be different. For example, this would be something that is true for all possible physical worlds, even if that truth supervenes on the physical. Empirical knowledge would refer to truths that do not have to be true in all possible physical worlds. Thus, one has to investigate and find out which of those physical worlds actually materializes.

" For example, this would be something that is true for all possible physical worlds" - Can you give an example? How can you a priori know something that must be true of all physical worlds?

@user80226 2+2=4 is a statement that would supervene on the physical but would be true for all possible physical worlds (from the perspective of a physicalist)

Why would  2+2=4 be necessarily true of all physical worlds? Why couldn't there be a physical world in which that is not true?

@user80226 can you think of a physical world where it would not be true? It’s similar to saying that the statement “there is a physical world” is true for all physical worlds, for obvious reasons

"can you think of a physical world where it would not be true?" - That's an appeal to lack of imagination. That's not a proof that it's not possible. But just imagine a world where under certain conditions if you put two things together they become one, or they become three, etc.

"It’s similar to saying that the statement “there is a physical world”" - This is a factual physical statement. However, 2+2=4 is not a factual physical statement. So you need to parse 2+2=4 into concrete physical statements, so that you can compare physical statements with physical statements. Otherwise it is just word salad. What do you mean by 2+2=4 physically?

I can't speak for anyone else, but what I mean by 2 + 2 = 4 physically is the definitions of the symbols and their relationship that reside inside my head, plus the identity of the equation and the implications people tend to associate with it, plus the caveat that it  has multiple representations depending on everything from which base we are working in to written formatting. Each of those presumably has further associations outward into my conceptual space which do not seem relevant for this illustration, and most of them drop out of focus when not constructing an illustration.

If you want to get more physical, exact state of individual neurons and patterns of feedback among them.

What is "a possible world"? Does this assume "there are" multiple physical (?) worlds and that "our" world is one of them? And further, does this assume that our everyday pre-theoretical talk about possibilities only makes sense in reference to those? So, it would amount to saying that anything possible is actually happening in some world? If so, how would you answer the question: How many worlds are there? And are all possible -- in relation to what? In relation to their collective? But what about their relation to "this" world?

Isn't it so that "possible worlds" are just fictive worlds, imagined worlds (and not even imagined in any level of detail or concreteness) which we have imagined to be (or stipulated to be) "real"? And then a priori truths are true because (apparently) they are true "in all possible worlds". But did we find them to be true in all those worlds? No, because no one ever actually visited or measured those worlds. So, how does a reference to "all possible worlds" make a priori truth less mysterious? How does it explain why they are found to be truth (or how they are discovered to be true)?

I do agree however that @user80226 seems to be confusing ontology and epistemology. On the other hand, the line between those two may be much fuzzier than most philosophers want to admit -- perhaps the two even blend over and are indistinguishable in some points (in regards to some questions). And that's especially so for math and logic (see for instance fictionalist or social-constructivist accounts).

First of all, our "knowledge of physics" as you refer to, is based on theories. In the context of science, the way-we-think is based explicitly in these theories. For example we understand gravity in terms of general relativity or newton law, we understand particles in terms of quantum mechanics etc. We now know that these theories with the accompanying mathematical models are nothing more that human structures. In Newton's time, people thought that they had discovered the laws of God; we know better. So our "knowledge of physics" is neither synthetic nor analytic (truths), but just our truths, in this specific point in time; it's just the way we look at things currently. As of the "empirical vs priori" part, knowledge always evolves, so it must be empirical.
But, I suspect that your question has to do with the truth of reality per se. And I answered with that introduction, in order to make the distinction between what we can-know about reality and what reality is. Because there exists a veil  between these two. And this veil, conveys the "analytic and a priori" aspect of reality to a "synthetic and empirical" one in our way of understanding it.
